# only required if checkbox is checked else text field must be left empty laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I understand the required_if. My issue is there is a checkbox or select where Other is checked or selected the Other Textfield is required. But is Other is not checked or selected that Particular Textfield should be empty. If it has anything is should give an error This Textfield Cannot must be blank since you did not select the option of others

Comment: You are having troubles about validation onserver side or client side?

Comment: It is the server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the request validation:

```
 'name_of_your_checkbox' => 'nullable'
 'name_of_your_textfield' => 'nullable|required_if:name_of_your_checkbox,checked'
```

Comment: Thanks this will give an error if the textfield is left blank, But what I am trying to figure out is if checkbox was not checked and the textfield was filled. It should give an error asking for the checkbox to be checked other wise to be empty

Comment: maybe you could add nullable to textfield as well

Comment: Thanks I tried it but still the same issue. I want it to give a error message saying This textfield must be blank since you have not checked the checkbox

Comment: required_if is working fine. If I check and leave the textfield blank it gives the error. What I want is now if I do not check and enter the textfield is also an error.this i what I am trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

**use required_if**
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if
**this is example**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'role_id' => Rule::requiredIf($request->user()->is_admin),
]);

Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'role_id' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return $request->user()->is_admin;
    }),
]);
```